# Sublime text auto library / package import

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, sublimetext3

I just love writing codes in SUBLIME Text. I am used to it. However IDEs are helpful while  writing codes for bigger projects. such as any maven projects. also it helps to auto import the necessary libs/packages from any jar war or packages.

Is there any way that sublime text can do the auto import like eclipse/IntelliJ

I will really appreciate the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (and pretty much only) Java plugin for Sublime is [`Javatar`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Javatar) - the full docs are [here](http://javatar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Modeled on Eclipse, Javatar tries its hardest to turn Sublime into a reasonably-functional Java IDE, at least as much as is possible given some of the limitations of Sublime. The package is quite complex, and takes some setup time to get fully functioning, but once you're all set it does include a lot of bells and whistles you may be missing from your favorite IDE. Make sure you install version 1, because apparently the autocompletion feature (which in my mind is one of the most important) is being removed in version 2 for some reason.